# Validating Password has a digit

Tags: javascript

So everything works in the following code, except for the validation of whether or not a password has a numerical digit. Can anyone see what may be wrong with my code here? It's acting like my password passes the test for numerical digits when it doesn't.

```
// Too short
//var password = "pass";

// Contains a space 
// password = "Contains space";

// Doesn't use a digit
password = "my-password";

// Repeats first and last 3 chars
//password = "abc123abc";

// Strong password
// password = "StrongPassword1";

// See if function returns an error message or not
var message = testPassword(password);
if (message) {
   console.log(message);
}
else {
   console.log("Password accepted.");
}

function testPassword(password) {

   var n = password;
   // Returns true if n is a string with a single digit, false otherwise
   var hasDigit = function isSingleDigit(n) {
      var unicodeValue = n.charCodeAt(0);
      return n.length === 1 && unicodeValue >= 48 && unicodeValue <= 57;
      };

   if (password.length < 6){

      return "Password must be at least 6 characters.";
   }

   if (password.indexOf(" ") != -1){
      return "Password may not contain a space.";  
   }

   if (hasDigit === false){
      return "Password must have at least one digit.";
   }

   if (password.substr(0, 3) === password.substr(-3)){
      return "The password may not begin and end with the same 3 characters.";
   }
   // Everything is good
   return "";
}
```

Console output:
Password accepted.

EDIT: Here was the fix. Thanks awesome community!

```
   var n = password;
   // Returns true if n is a string with a single digit, false otherwise
   function isSingleDigit(n) {
      var unicodeValue = n.charCodeAt(0);
      return n.length === 1 && unicodeValue >= 48 && unicodeValue <= 57;
      }

   var hasDigit = isSingleDigit(n);
```

Comment: `var hasDigit = function isSingleDigit(n) {` assignes the function `isSingleDigit` to the variable `hasDigit`. (It doesn't call `isSingleDigit`with the variable `n`) What is the reason that you write it that way instead of defining the function `isSingleDigit` outside of `testPassword` and calling it in `testPassword`?

Comment: Because I am just new at this! Thanks for helping me. You are right. Here's the fix:

Comment: Don't place `Javascript` in the title, that's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `hasDigit` has the definition of the function itself and not the return value since it was never called.

Change your if statement to

```
if (hasDigit(n) === false){
    return "Password must have at least one digit.";
}
```

**Edit**

However, I don't think the function would still work correctly as this function would only return true if the `password`is a single digit as opposed to a string containing at least one digit.

Comment: Yall are awesome!! Removing the variable from being set to the original hasDigit function and instead setting that variable to the called function worked. I'll edit to reflect the solution. Thanks for your knowledge and help.

Comment: @Amber You are welcome. However, please see the new edit.

Comment: thank you I put the edit for the solution in the original post. Of course I needed to call my function as you said! It worked :)